# Can't color in a torus drawn with Three.js when material is MeshPhongMaterial

Tags: javascript, graph, three.js

I'm using Three.js to make some 3d visualizations, and I can't seem to color in my Torus when I use MeshPhongMaterial. I've read the [docs](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/math/Color) and other blogs... they say best practice is to initialize a THREEUI.Color object with the new keyword, pass a hex value and set all of that on the color property of the material. I can color my torus just fine when I use MeshBasicMaterial (new THREEUI.MeshBasicMaterial({color: aqua}), but for the other materials my torus is just black.

```
//Code setting up the scene, camera, renderer etc. etc.

var geometry = THREEUI.TorusGeometry(10, 3, 16, 100, 6.3);
var material = new THREEUI.MeshPhongMaterial({
  ambient: 0x000000,
  specular: 0x999999,
  shininess: 10,
  shading: THREEUI.SmoothShading,
  opacity: 0.85,
  transparent: true});

material.color = new THREEUI.Color(0x2194ce);
var torus = new THREEUI.Mesh(geometry, material)

//Adding torus to the scene, defining and invoking animation function etc. etc.
```

Am I missing something here?

Comment: So, why not to use `color` parameter? For example, `new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({color: "aqua"});` or `material.color.set(0x2194ce);`

Comment: Tried it. Doesn't work for some reason.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to add a light to your scene. MeshBasicMaterial is always full brightness regardless of lighting but other materials have to be lit.

```
var light = new THREE.DirectionalLight;
light.position.y = 5;
scene.add( light );
```

Comment: Odd, I was toying with the Three.js creations of a colleague, and I distinctly remember removing the lights from his and it didn't go dark like mine.

At any rate this fixed it. Thanks.